# Access row wise data from PostgreSQL table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have cascading dropdown list district and Taluk.when I select district it's showing taluks of corresponding district in 2nd dropdown list.now when I select one Taluk it should display gridview of corresponding taluk's details.

Comment: Is this question really a PostgreSQL/sql question? and you should write question so that people cud understand what you want without using Wikipedia or a dictionary. i asume taluk means city or town

Comment: in what programming language are you programming this?

Comment: I am using postgresql database.c# language I am using